# Method I add with Bytebuddy is not being called, but there are no errors

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I am trying to add a method to an existing class at run-time with Bytebuddy, and I'm receiving no errors but not getting my expected output. This is my agent:

```
public class Agent {

    public static void premain(String arguments, Instrumentation instrumentation) {

        System.out.println("Agent for add a method ");

        new AgentBuilder.Default()
                .with(new AgentBuilder.InitializationStrategy.SelfInjection.Eager())
                .type((ElementMatchers.nameContains("cup")))
                .transform((builder, typeDescription, classLoader, module) -> builder
                        .defineMethod("method3", void.class, Visibility.PUBLIC)
                        .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(AddMethod.class))
                        .method(ElementMatchers.any())
                        .intercept(SuperMethodCall.INSTANCE
                                .andThen(MethodCall.invoke(ElementMatchers.nameContains("method3"))))
                ).installOn(instrumentation);

    }
}
```

The expected output should be this function called:

```
    public static void method3() throws Exception {

       System.out.println("This is method 3");

    }
```

The output from the command line when ran is just

```
Agent for add a method
hello world
```

This is the java file that I'm trying to instrument.

```
public class cuppy {
    public static void main (String args [])
    {
         method1();
    }

    public static void method1 ()
    {
        System.out.println("hello world);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the brightest.

It calls the function on the invocation of an object and I wasn't ever invoking an object in my cuppy class.

Once I changed the cuppy main function to

```
 cuppy cup = new cuppy();
         cup.method1();
```

it did what I expected.

Answer (score 0):

As for debugging such issues, always add a `AgentBuilder.Listener` as errors during instrumentations are always suppressed by the JVM. Glad you figured out your problem.